# 「window.innerWidth」と「window.matchMedia」の違い

Tags: javascript

**両者の違いが分かりません**
・[window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)
・[window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

・それぞれ戻り値が異なると思うのですが、「window.matchMedia」の戻り値である「 MediaQueryList オブジェクト」は、内部で「window.innerWidth」処理をしているわけではないのでしょうか？

---

試しに、

```
window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 400px)" )
```

をコンソール表示すると、下記になります

```
MediaQueryList {media: "(min-width: 400px)", matches: true, onchange: null}
```

---

**「window.matchMedia」は引数内容がマッチしているかどうかを返すだけなので、実際の幅は返さない？**
・マッチしているかどうかの判定はどこで行っているのでしょうか？
・「`__proto__`」の「get matches関数」？
・そこで「window.innerWidth」を使用しているかどうかは分からない？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

window.innerWidthは、ブラウザウィンドウの ビューポート の幅を返します。
返り値は、整数（ピクセル）です。

window.matchMediaは、引数に指定されたメディアがビューポートの中に合う(match)かどうかを判断します。
返り値は、trueかfalseのどちらかです。

window.matchMediaで行われる処理では、引数に指定されたメディアの属性と、ビューポートの属性の比較が行われるでしょうが、必ずしもwindow.innerWidthが使われるとは限りません。

例えば、window.matchMedia( "(min-hight: 240px)" )　というような使われ方だと、幅は関係ないので、window.innerWidthは使われないと思います。